# Macros in Swift?

Tags: macros, swift

Does Swift currently support macros, or are there future plans to add support? Currently I'm scattering:

```
Log.trace(nil, function: __FUNCTION__, file: __FILE__, line: __LINE__)
```

In various places throughout my code.

Comment: *[Write Swift macros](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10166)*. At [WWDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Worldwide_Developers_Conference) 2023.

Comment: [Search query here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=macros%20swift&searchOn=3). [Tags only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros%2bswift?tab=Newest) (only one hit June 2023).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In this case you should add a default value for the "macro" parameters.

*Swift 2.2 and higher*

```
func log(message: String,
        function: String = #function,
            file: String = #file,
            line: Int = #line) {

     print("Message \"\(message)\" (File: \(file), Function: \(function), Line: \(line))")
}

log("Some message")
```

*Swift 2.1 and lower*

```
func log(message: String,
        function: String = __FUNCTION__,
        file: String = __FILE__,
        line: Int = __LINE__) {

    print("Message \"\(message)\" (File: \(file.lastPathComponent), Function: \(function), Line: \(line))")
}

log("Some message")
```

This is what `fatalError` and `assert` functions do.

There are no other macros except the conditional compilation already mentioned in another answer.

Comment: interesting to see `__FUNCTION__` is evaluated in caller context

Comment: @BryanChen Yeah, I noticed the default values in the `assert` declaration so I did some experimenting.

Comment: `__FILE__` will store the whole path to the file into the variable file. So if you want to tidy up your console output, you may consider to use `\(file.lastPathComponent)` instead of `\(file)` so you only get the filename of the swift file itself.

Comment: @crosscode `__FILE__` is a compile time constant, Swift uses string interning, so the function param only gets the pointer to the string, which is almost free. Even if there are 10 log() calls in this file, the same constant is pointed to, and no new memory gets allocated. lastPathComponent defeats that, generates a new string at runtime. In the example this doesn't matter because of print, but consider a different logging in production: ringbuffers (arrays of string/int) for line, file, function, and message seperately. Works great for us, but you should keep strings untouched in that case.

Comment: note about string interning in Swift: https://github.com/vandadnp/swift-weekly/blob/master/issue03/README.md#string-enumerations-in-swift

Comment: @hko String interning is completely irrelevant for logging, even with production logging. Logging in production will always slightly decrease performance but discussing whether `lastPathComponent` will slightly change memory usage is far beyond the line of over-optimization.

Comment: @Sulthan Oh, I have to respectfully disagree here.. it's certainly not _completely_ irrelevant. In the case I intend, which is tracing every touch event for a record/replay system, I need the fastest logging, without interfering with touch perf. Most apps just logging business logic? Probably overkill, but not a real drawback either, in my book. Trace logging? Very usefull. Plus in the future on the serverside.. very usefull. Different usecases, different implementations. Don't be that guy that dismisses usecases outside his realm as irrelevant.

Comment: @hko If you are logging events for a replay system then saving them as a string seems a bit strange. Also, that's a very different use case from debug logs we are discussing here.

Comment: "Also, that's a very different use case from debug logs we are discussing here." Interesting. Couldn't find that in the original question or your answer. Logging is logging. In addition: the original question uses "Log.trace", which to me is very often a.. tracelog. Perf sometimes matters. If you need faster logging, you can use my tip. But don't argue it's "irrelevant".

Comment: What about a situation where you want to only log under debug mode

Answer (score 20):

The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html) state that:

> Declare simple macros as global constants, and translate complex macros into functions.

You can still use #if/#else/#endif - but my feeling is that they will not introduce macro functions, the language simply doesn't need it.

Comment: What about preprocessor macros useful for compiling for iOS and OS X in the same file?

Comment: @adib the `#if` style macros work, and are perfect for this kind of task

Comment: "the language simply doesn't need it"... I've seen this in the docs somewhere. My experience migrating from Java to C strongly suggests that a language without a decent preprocessor is bound to produce long-winded forms sooner or later.

Comment: @tea I stopped missing macros in Java with the introduction of annotations and the maturation of APT. Does swift have anything comparable?

Comment: Swift seems to have annotations (`@objc`, `@IBAction`, `@IBOutlet`...) but does not seem to have a way for developers to define their own yet.

Comment: No a language don't need macro, If you can't add a macro like lisp, you would better have a macro like C, if you don't have both, it's a sad thing.

Comment: Apple should at least acknowledge that without macros, certain things are just plain impossible, like printing both an expression and its value in one go (the equivalent of python's `print(f"{x=}")`.

Answer (score 7):

Since XCode 7.3, the `__FILE__` `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` compile-time constants have become the nicer-looking `#file` `#function` and `#line` respectively.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an updated Swift 2 answer.

```
func LogW(msg:String, function: String = #function, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line){
    print("[WARNING]\(makeTag(function, file: file, line: line)) : \(msg)")
}

private func makeTag(function: String, file: String, line: Int) -> String{
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file)
    let className = url.lastPathComponent ?? file
    return "\(className) \(function)[\(line)]"
}
```

Example of use:

```
LogW("Socket connection error: \(error)")
```

Comment: I'm glad some of the answers added the NSURL code. That being said, why not use the [Nil Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html). For example, `let className = url.lastPathComponent ?? file`.

Answer (score 4):

`lastPathComponent` needs an `NSURL`, so I changed the above code to this:

```
func log(message: String,
    function: String = __FUNCTION__,
    file: String = __FILE__,
    line: Int = __LINE__) {

        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file)

        print("Message \"\(message)\" (File: \(url.lastPathComponent ?? "?"), Function: \(function), Line: \(line))")
}

log("some message")
```

Answer (score 0):

A macro proposal is going through Swift Evolution right now. This would allow you to define a custom type that could create a macro that can be evaluated at compile time, like the C stringify macro, for example.

https://forums.swift.org/t/se-0382-expression-macros/62090

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It *seems* [to have happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114288/macros-in-swift#comment134814397_24114288).

Answer (score -1):

There is way to use macros on swift (but this used in Mixed of objective c and swift)

declare your macros into `Project-name-Bridging-Header.h`

```
#define  YOUR_MACRO @"Description"
```

or create separate header file for macros `"macros.h"`

import this header "macros.h" in to your Bridging-Header.h file..

now just save your project your macros will came in swift file ..

if you don't wanna object c code on your swift project... just create dummy cocoa touch classes it will create bridging header then use my way...

Comment: That simply will not work on complex macros. You HAVE to recreate using functions.