# _cmd_/__FUNCTION__ in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objective-C I like to write:

```
printf("%s", __FUNCTION__)
```

or

```
printf("%s", __cmd__)
```

How can this be done in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motly the same

```
println(__FUNCTION__)
```

There is no `__cmd__` of course.

Also see [Macros in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114288/macros-in-swift/24116621#24116621)