# Global macros in Swift

Tags: ios, macros, swift, constants

What is the best way to use global macros in Swift (If this is what is called, english is not my mother tongue sorry). I am looking for a way to have all the macros/keys in on place, maybe a class.

I used to put all my app keys in the Precompiled Header file (.phc), but like I saw in another post this is probably not the best practice:

[Why .pch file not available in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113256/why-pch-file-not-available-in-swift)

For example if I would like to have a bunch of constant keys that the values are just Int, what would you recommend to use in Swift?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a Swift file with everything you need as global functions if you really want. For example, create a new Swift file named `Globals.swift`. In this file, you do not need any class or struct declarations. Define functions at a global scope, and they are available the same as any other method, like the global `contains` method.

Comment: Thanks! I will go with this one. Sorry I have not enough reputation to give you an up vote so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a Struct or an Enum at global scope.