# PCH file in Swift Project

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I have an existing Objective-C Project that I am making into a Swift Project.

That is I have a lot of Objective-c code that I will keep and Swifting away going forward.

I have managed to create and import almost everything, but the PCH file is giving me problems.

First step is just to use the x-Prefix.pch file from objc in same project and then afterwards from Swift.

When I reference something like `typedef` or "`#define`" in the PCH file it can not see it?

1. I have added the "Prefix Header" to the target
2. Set "Precompile Prefix Header" to "YES"

Lastly the compiler do find the xx-Prefix.pch file but I can not use any `define` or `typedef` in code elsewere.

Do you know how?

Comment: Are you talking about using the prefix header from Swift code?

Comment: Nope: Use of unresolved identifier

Comment: Check this @ChrisG. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113256/why-pch-file-not-available-in-swift

Comment: I did see that one. I guess it is time then :-) Thanks

Comment: ChrisG, it's not clear whether this is a duplicate of the question pedrouan links, or if you believe there is more to it? If it's a dupe, we can mark it such so that future searchers will be directed to the answer, but I don't want to do that if you have a deeper question.

Comment: Hi @Rob Napier You are absolutely right, it became clear to me that the answer is what pedrouan linked to. Thanks for asking! I can also just delete the question?