# import XXNibBridge into my project, but semantic issue occurs saying [unknown type name 'link'] after running this project

Tags: ios

1. XXNibBridge is imported into PCH file of my project
2. Run this project, semantic issue occurs, saying `[Unknown type name 'link']`

[image: click to see the screenshot]

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `link` (I don't even know what you are trying to do there) and instead use `#import` (or `#include`).

If you'd like to know more about pch files (or even if you should use them -- which you don't have to, more often than not), there are related questions here on StackOverflow where you can get more information.  Like:

[What is Prefix.pch file in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648593/what-is-prefix-pch-file-in-xcode)

[Why isn't ProjectName-Prefix.pch created automatically in Xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158648/why-isnt-projectname-prefix-pch-created-automatically-in-xcode-6)

[Why .pch file not available in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113256/why-pch-file-not-available-in-swift)

Comment: yes, i used #import, but the error just showed like that. This project just handed to me and I'm the only iOS engineer right now...

Comment: Just try changing the `link` to `#import` and see things compile better.  I suspect the `link` was somebody's mistype along the way.