# Create parameterised string or macro in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am new to Swift and I want to know that how can I create parameterised strings or macros in Swift ?

Like we do in Objective-C :

```
#define SEARCH(name, limits) [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://someURL.com/search?term=%@&limit=%ld", name, limits]
```

How can formulate above statement in Swift ?

Comment: for better or worse Swift [just does not have](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html) preprocessor macros ..   [more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24114340/294884)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define global function:

```
func search(name: String, _ limits: Int) -> String {
    return "https://someURL.com/search?term=\(name)&limit=\(limits)"
}
```

Also do not forget to URL-encode `name`:

```
func search(name: String, _ limits: Int) -> String {
    let urlEncodedName = name.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) ?? ""
    return "https://someURL.com/search?term=\(urlEncodedName)&limit=\(limits)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use same code in Bridge-Header

```
#define SEARCH(name, limits) [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://someURL.com/search?term=%@&limit=%ld", name, limits]
```

same as

```
#define kNSUserDefaultUserInfo "UserInfo"
```

I tried your code in my Project Bridge-Header and its accessible from all files whether it is Swift or Objective C.

Hope this will help you

Comment: I tried this, but it not works for me. After adding it in bridge header file, how to use?