# How to define custom localize constant in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift 2 . I know define macro in objective c as

```
#define MYAPPCLocalize(Key) NSLocalizedStringFromTable(Key, APP_DELEGATE.currentStrings, @"N/A")
```

But how can i declare like the same in swift . Please help me

Comment: Follow solution provided in this link. I had same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213218/create-parameterised-string-or-macro-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html):

```
Declare simple macros as global constants, and translate complex macros into functions.
```

You can translate your code this way:

```
func MYAPPCLocalize(key: String) -> String {
  return NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, APP_DELEGATE.currentStrings, "N/A")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

Actually in swift there no concept of Macros. If you want to create simple macro then you can create it with `let` keyword which treated as a macro or something like static variable(attribute).

If you want to create parameterised macro, then create `func` with parameters and return type.

Follow solution provided in this link

[Create parameterised string or macro in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213218/create-parameterised-string-or-macro-in-swift)