# How to define constant in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, constants

I searched a lot over the internet to find the right solution to convert my constant .h file to swift.
  I already tried these links

1. [how to use a objective-c define from swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325477/how-to-use-a-objective-c-define-from-swift)
2. [Globalconstants file in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252233/global-constants-file-in-swift)

These both are use full but not completely solved my problem.

I just want to convert these three #define to swift all other can be converted in the same way as these will do.

1. `#define IS_IPHONE_4S        [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480`
2. `#define IOS7VERSION ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=7.0?YES:NO)`
3. `#define RGBCOLOR(r, g, b)       [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0f green:(g)/255.0f blue:(b)/255.0f alpha:1]`

Comment: These are not constants, these are macros. Just replace them with functions.

Comment: constant is defined using 'let' keyword in swift  but according to above code , if you want how to define macros in swift then http://stackoverflow.com/a/24116621/3400991 will help . Thanks

Comment: The first one of these is totally broken. Turn your phone sideways, and suddenly it's not an iPhone 4 anymore.

Comment: @gnasher729 what if I am working on only portrait mode ?

Comment: @gnasher729 Turngate!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the keyword `let` for this.
For example:

```
let IsIPhone4S = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height == 480
let IOS7Version = Float(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion) >= 7
```

And for the last case you should use function:

```
func RGBColor(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: red / 255, green: green / 255, blue: blue / 255, alpha: 1)
}
```

Comment: @VarunNaharia, so why don't you approve the answer?