# custom console log in swift

Tags: swift, logging, console

I would like to implement a custom print function in SWIFT(3) similar to console.log used by JavaScript.

The ideal pattern will the following:
`Console.log(msg:"my message")`

Then the Console static class will print to console as : `Log:my message [myfile.swift : (123, 40)]` (where 123 is the line number and 40 the position or column)

The equivalent Console.warn(msg:...) and Console.error(msg:...) would produce the following output.

`Warn:my message [myfile.swift : (123, 40)]`

`Error:my message [myfile.swift : (123, 40)]`

I can use #file and keep just the last path component but I cannot use #line and #column because it will always show the values of my static method implementation and not where there Console.log method was actually called in the code.

So, I will get

```
Warn:my message [Console.swift : (28, 30)]
```

And not the wished

```
Warn:my message [somefile.swift : (123, 40)]
```

assuming that `Console.log(msg:"my message")` was called in file some file.swft at lint 123.

So the question is: how to achieve the printing of line number from the calling function.

Comment: The "trick" is to pass #file, #line etc as the default values of optional arguments. Explained also in this blog entry https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15.

Comment: Another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114288/macros-in-swift

Comment: perfect.. Thank you