# Writing Macro in Swift 3 with examples

Tags: ios, swift, macros

I have a block of codes which I would like to use often in my project. It would be a good practice to create macros for a specific lines of codes and call it later. I have the following code block:

```
var imageViewObject :UIImageView
imageViewObject = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 600))
imageViewObject.image = UIImage(named:"afternoon")
self.view.addSubview(imageViewObject)
```

Can you refer swift guideline and examples for creating macros?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [Macros in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114288/macros-in-swift).  There are no macros in Swift.  You should create reusable code in extensions or public functions.

Comment: There are no macros, and that's a good thing. C-style macros are a nightmare of type non-safety, and should die.

Answer (score 1):

### No macros in Swift

As *@JAL* already explained there are not macros in Swift.

### Creating an extension

Your code is a good candiate for an extension of `UIView`, like this

```
extension UIView {
    func addImageView(imageName: String) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:600, height:600))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"afternoon")
        addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Now inside your view controller you simply write

```
self.view.addImageView(imageName: "afternoon")
```

here's a full example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addImageView(imageName: "afternoon")
    }
}
```