# How to get the name of the current file, module, and procedure in Chapel

Tags: chapel

In Chapel, is it possible to get the name of the current file, module, or procedure by some means (e.g., via a helper function)? My goal here is to print the routine name without writing it explicitly by hand in `writeln()`.

```
proc calculate_this_and_that_ver2() {
  // writeln( "In calculate_this_and_that_ver2()" ); // long...
  writeln( "In ", modname(), " : ", procname() );
  ...
}
```

What I wish here may be similar to something like [`#function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114288/macros-in-swift) etc in Swift:

```
func mytest() {
   print( "file =", #file, "func =", #function, "line =", #line )
}
mytest()  // --> file = test.swift func = mytest() line = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that Chapel currently has support for a feature like this, though it has been discussed from time to time and has generally been received positively in those conversations.  I would recommend filing a feature request future against it on our [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues).