# How to Write Macros in Swift

Tags: swift

For example, we can use macros in C++ to write a simplified version of a similar name, as in the source code below, but can you do the same in Swift?

```cpp
void AddStats(const Stats& add_from, Stats* add_to) {
    add_to->set_total_memory(add_from.total_memory() + add_to->total_memory());
    add_to->set_free_memory(add_from.total_memory() + add_to->free_memory());
    add_to->set_swap_memory(add_from.total_memory() + add_to->swap_memory());
    add_to->set_status_string(add_from.total_memory() + add_to->status_string());
    add_to->set_num_processes(add_from.total_memory() + add_to->num_processes());
    ...
}
```

We can write the above in the following way.

```cpp
void AddStats(const Stats& add_from, Stats* add_to) {
    #define ADD_FIELD(field) add_to->set##field(add_from.field() + add_to->field())
    ADD_FIELD(total_memory);
    ADD_FIELD(free_memory);
    ADD_FIELD(swap_memory);
    ADD_FIELD(status_string);
    ADD_FIELD(num_processes);
    ...
    #undef ADD_FIELD
}
```

I want to write the same way in Swift, but I don't know how.
Can someone please tell me how to do it?

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum testEnum: String{
    case hoge
    case tage
    case hige
}


private let hoge = 1
private let tage = 2
private let hige = 3


struct Content: View{
    let num: testEnum = .hoge
    var body: some View {
        if num == .hoge {
            Text("\(hoge)")
        } else if num == .tage {
            Text("\(tage)")
        } else if num == .hige {
            Text("\(hige)")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what it is you want to do here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Macros in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114288/macros-in-swift)

Comment: Swift doesn’t have a macro system. Most code reuse is achieved through functions and extensions to protocols

Answer (score 2):

You can simplifiy your code to this.

```
enum TestEnum: Int{
    case hoge = 1
    case tage = 2
    case hige = 3
}

struct Content: View{
    let num: TestEnum = .hoge
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(num.rawValue)")
        
    }
}
```